# CLLocationManager does not have allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates member variable

Tags: cordova, ios8, ios9, cllocationmanager

I am taking my iOS8 app and getting it ready for iOS9. I have read that CLLocationManager now has a member variable called allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates that needs to be set to true for iOS9. However, Xcode does not recognize this as a member of CLLocationManager. What do I need to change to get Xcode to recognize that attribute? I am running Xcode 7.

```
    - (BOOL)isLocationServicesEnabled
    {
        BOOL locationServicesEnabledInstancePropertyAvailable = [self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)]; // iOS 3.x
        BOOL locationServicesEnabledClassPropertyAvailable = [CLLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)]; // iOS 4.x

        if (locationServicesEnabledClassPropertyAvailable) { // iOS 4.x
            return [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
         } else if (locationServicesEnabledInstancePropertyAvailable) { // iOS 2.x, iOS 3.x
            return [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature (`allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates`) is iOS 9 only. Note that it is an *instance* property, not a class property.

As long as you are linking against iOS 8 you won't have to worry about it, as it won't affect you even if you run on iOS 9. If you are linking against iOS 9 you must set this property on every CLLocationManager instance you are holding, or your background location updates won't happen.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates

Comment: how do i set this property? i have tried CLLocationManagerInstance.allowBackgroundLocaitonUpdates = YES; but it does not recognize that instance property.

Comment: I don't know Cordoba. I only know how to do it normally in Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am editing actual Objective-C code. Cordova basically creates a Xcode project in Objective-C that is a web view. This allows you to take apps written in javascript (with html and css for the view) and turn them in to mobile apps. Right now I am trying to edit the Objective-C part of the Cordova project. I have added some of the code to my original post.